# I keep getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" Error

Tags: mysql, next.js, compiler-errors

I keep getting that error while using this code. The problem keeps popping up despite having trying a key thing I thought would fix it. Is there anyway I can fix it?

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const[dataResponse, setdataResponse] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPageData() {
            const apiUrlEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/api/games';
            const response = await fetch(apiUrlEndpoint);
            const res = await response.json();
            console.log(res.games);
            setdataResponse(res.games);
        }
        getPageData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className='bg-gray-100 min-h-screen'>
            
            {dataResponse.map((games) => {
                return (
                    <div key= {games.ProductID}>
                        <div>{games.ProductName}</div>
                    <div>
                        <img src={games.ProductImage} alt=""/>
                    </div>
                        <div>
                            {games.ProductDescription}
                        </div>
                    <div>
                        {games.DateWhenAdded}
                    </div>
                </div>   
             )
            })}
    </div>
);
}
```

This is my API, which is games.js:

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

 export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const dbconnection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        database: "onlinestore",
        port: 3306,
        user: "root",
        password: "This is Private, I'm not showing password",
    });
    try {
        const query = "SELECT ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductImage, ProductPrice, DateWhenAdded FROM games"
        const values = [];
        const [games] = await dbconnection.execute(query, values);
        dbconnection.end();
        for (const game of games) {
            game.ProductImage = `data:image/webp;base64,${games.ProductImage.toString('base64')}`;
            game.DateWhenAdded = formatDistanceToNowStrict(games.DateWhenAdded);
        }
        res.status(200).json(games);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
 }
```

One thing I did try was trying the ? after the dataResponse, and seeing if I put in an "if" statement to make sure it exists, and to post something after it if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by reworking my whole code in a sense and adding in a different property that allowed me to take the mysql date and turn it into JS date format and making sure that error no longer appears.